# Thymeleaf iteration status variable is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

This is my data class survey nothing unusual here I even have eager loading to prevent issues

```
package com.based.basedsurvey.data;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Survey {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @NonNull
    private String name;
    private boolean open;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();

    public Survey(String name){
        this.name = name;
        open = false;
    }
}
```

in the controller this is also very standard just returning all of the items

```
    @GetMapping(path = "/")
    public String homePage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("surveys", surveyRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(0,10)));
        return "index";
    }
```

repository class

```
package com.based.basedsurvey.repo;

import com.based.basedsurvey.data.Survey;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface SurveyRepository extends JpaRepository<Survey, Long> {
    Survey findSurveyById(long id);

}
```

html, this is a small snippet, the important part is surveyStat.odd and surveyStat.last

```
 <tbody>
    <tr th:each="survey: ${surveys}" th:class="${surveyStat.odd}? 'odd'">
        <td>
          <div th:attr="hx-reveal=${surveyStat.last ? 'revealed' : null}"></div>
          <p th:text="${survey.isOpen()?'OPEN':'CLOSED'}"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

`EL1021E: A problem occurred whilst attempting to access the property 'last': 'Unable to access property 'last' through getter method'`

`Unable to access property 'last' through getter method`

`Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because "this.size" is null`

I'm not sure why when i use surveyStat.odd there is no issue but when I use surveyStat.last I'm given an error and the index page is no longer able to load

There is no issue on compilation but rather when the view index is attempting to load the error EL1021E shown below is thrown.

Comment: Where's your class `SurveyStat`?

Comment: @QBrute SurveyStat is automatically provided by thymeleaf to give iteration stats
https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-iteration#status-variable

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, but judging from the example at Baeldung, shouldn't it be `th:each="survey, surveyStat: ${surveys}"`?

Comment: @QBrute In case we omit the explicit creation of status variable (presented as iStat in our example), we could invoke our status variable by simply using the studentStat, which is the aggregation of the variable student with the suffix Stat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
surveyRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(0,10))
```

returns a `Page<T>` (provided your `surveyRepository` is a default [PagingAndSortingRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html))

This `Page` neither implements `Collection` nor `Map` and it isn't an array. But it implements `Iterable` so thymeleaf will compute the size as `null`. You can check the relevant code [here](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/blob/e5434ee1dc5145c8a2a5ff50a40bffa16c63a412/lib/thymeleaf/src/main/java/org/thymeleaf/engine/IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.java#L410).

What you could do is instead of passing the `Page` to the model pass a `Collection` instead:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/")
public String homePage(Model model) {
    List<Survey> surveys = surveyRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(0,10)).getContent();
    model.addAttribute("surveys", surveys);
    return "index";
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I am using a JPA repository, would I just need to put this method in the surveyRepository class and implement the branch for an iterator to have this working then?

Comment: I added a possible solution. Let me know if it works.